# Make an element to take up remaining space without flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have a situation in which I have two elements floated next to each other, neither of which can have an explicit width - their widths are defined by their contents which is dynamic.

I need the element on the right hand side to take up as much remaining vertical space in the row of elements as possible without setting any kind of width.

I'm currently trying to phase out the use of flexbox, due to complaints from clients about browser incompatibilities when using it (mostly in IE).

Below is an example of a scenario in which I would like to achieve this effect.

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 700px;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
nav ul {
  background-color: blue;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
form {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    <ul>
  </nav>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Use tables or calc css

Comment: @Shadow calc would require knowing the size of other things?

Comment: fyi, you have a markup error, that <ul> both opening no closing.

Answer (score 4):

That's why we love flexbox, but yeah, give up and use tables if you have to support an old browser that is not supported by MS anymore. Don't give a width to the fluid columns, give the last one 100%;

```css
table td:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Bigger&nbsp;content</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By the way, [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639764/227299) is better; it uses just CSS to get the table effect. In that case, you don't get to mock whoever is requiring you to support that dinosaur.

```css
ul {display: table}
li {display: table-cell}
li:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Bigger&nbsp;content</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` to mimic flex parents and flex children with better browser support.

Setting the parent to `display: table;` and the children to `display: table-cell;` can achieve that layout.

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 700px;
  display: table;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}

form {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav class="cell">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        <ul>
    </nav>
    <form class="cell">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That feels a little less dirty than mine, pretends like you're not using table layout

Comment: @JuanMendes yeah, it's  a better approach. You shouldn't use table markup if the content isn't tabular data. If you just want the design to mimic a table, use CSS since that's what CSS is for.

Comment: I know, I just don't care about people who force us to still have to support a dinosaur of a browser, they deserve table layouts on their apps ;p

Comment: @JuanMendes haha `<!--[if lt IE 10]><script>while (true) { alert('upgrade your browser!'); }</script><![endif]-->`